# How to create a transparent scrollbar in android?

Tags: android

I have a transparent listview with a image as background. Now, i want the scrollbar as transparent too, i.e I must be able to see the background image through this scrollbar too. Pls help!!!

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="..."
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="..."
```

Where ... is a reference to your transparent drawable.

Answer (score 7):

In your XML, if you add the line

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

your ListView will still scroll, but have no visible scrollbars.

Comment: Thank u for the reply!In the case you said, the scrollbar will not be visible at all, but my requirement is like.. the scrollbar of my Listview must be transparent and the text or background under it should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to this post:

[scrollBar in a listView...customizing it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880720/scrollbar-in-a-listview-customizing-it)

They describe how to create a customized scrollbar with a given image.  Your solution would be to create an image with some alpha value as to make it as transparent or as opaque as you want.

Oh yeah, make sure your image is a .PNG file as jpegs do not contain alpha information, so the cannot do transparency.