# scrollBar in a listView...customizing it.

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, customization

Is there a way to customize the standard scrollbar that ListView provides in android..? I haven't got a definitive answer on this yet :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a theme in `res/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scroll_track</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroll_thumb</item>
</style>
```

`@drawable/scroll_track` and `@drawable/scroll_thumb` must refer either to nine patch images or to a shape drawables. Scroll track image is a background for the scroll bar. Scroll thumb is responsible for the scroll handle. Then just apply the theme either to whole application or to an activity within AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Comment: oh cool This seems very interesting... So when creating the drawable scroll_track and scroll_thumb.. can it just be a gradient?

Comment: @cj1098 it can be any drawable in fact. Just experiment until you get what you want.

Comment: the image used as thumb is stretching.. even though i m using a 9patch image, i m not getting the desired result.......

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify it in the ListView or ScrollView that is in your layout. I have a provided a screenshot example from my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opszB.jpg)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="500"
    android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="1000">
</ListView>
```