# Set size and Position of the scrollbar in Android?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am working on a ListView in which I have to set the size of the scroll bar.
Also the position of scroll-bar to the LEFT side of the screen.

I have used a custom Scroll-bar with code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#33b8e9"
        android:startColor="#33b8e9" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
    <size android:width="2dip"
        android:height="5dip"/>
</shape>
```

but still getting a scrollbar with huge lengh as shown in figure.:
[image]

but I need scrollbars like this image.
[image]

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880720/scrollbar-in-a-listview-customizing-it